# find the interval of m so that the equation will have 4 answers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

find the interval of m so that the equation will have 4 answers
$$ |x-2| + |x+2| - \sqrt{|x|}= m $$ I solved the problem by plotting , but couldn't solve it algebraically . easy question but I think needs some tricks ...

Comment: When you solved the problem by plotting, what answer did you get?  If you know the answer, that is half the battle.  You now have to prove that is the answer.

Comment: Hint:  To get the square root sign, use \sqrt {stuff}  That makes the bar go above stuff like you would like.  If stuff is a single character you don't need the braces.

Comment: @StefanSmith 4 - √2 , 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hint

**The *soft* method**

**Step 1**:

Find the interval in the curve $y=|x+2|+|x-2|$ where the gradient is $0$. Loosely speaking this means that the curve has no real control on what goes on here. Therefore adding another curve will override this part. Now the curve $y=-\sqrt{|x|}$ is symmetrical along the $y$ axis there fore will always have two solutions. It can also be thought of as the negative part of the curve $y^2=|x|$.

**Step 2**:

Find the maximum and minimum value of $y=-\sqrt{|x|}$ in the interval $(2, -2)$ (Note that it is symmetrical). Adding this curve to the $y=|x+2|+|x-2|$ curve does not disturb the $y=|x+2|+|x-2|$ curve therefore the interval constructed from your maximum and minimum values will give you 4 answers.

**The rigorous method**

*Techniques and hints*

- Try constructing some inequalities with the absolute values. Use the fact that $|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$
- Finding a finite extema for your equation would hint at an interval